# Flexbox pushing the center of my elements

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to do a betting app, with a wireframe like this:

[image: wireframe]

For that, im using this code bellow:

```
       <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          flexFlow: "row nowrap",
          justifyContent: "space-around",
          alignItems: "stretch"
        }}
      >
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: "yellow", flex:1 }}>
          <div style={{justifyContent: "flex-start", display: "flex",
          flexFlow: "row nowrap"}} >
            <div>FLAG</div>  
            <div>HOME_TEAM</div>  
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: "red" , flex:1}}>
          <div style={{justifyContent: "center", display: "flex",
          flexFlow: "row nowrap"}} >
            <div>Input1</div>  
            <div>x</div>
            <div>Input2</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: "yellow", flex:1 }}>
          <div style={{justifyContent: "flex-end", display: "flex",
          flexFlow: "row nowrap"}} >
            <div>AWAY_TEAM</div>  
            <div>FLAG</div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
```

When the AWAY_TEAM and HOME_TEAM have the same size. The things looks good, like these:

[image: working]

But if the AWAY_TEAM name has a different length it starts "pushing" the other divs; 
[image: wrong]

But I want that my INPUTS keeps always on center.

What Im doing wrong on my CSS?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce somehow: https://codesandbox.io/s/8yqp09wz78

Comment: try to play with `flex-grow` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the input section to remain in the center, the home-team and away-team sections need to *always be the same width*.

So, if you know what `width` you want the inputs section to be, - say `120px` - then you'll also know that you'll always want the home-team and away-team sections to have the width:

```
calc((100% - 120px) / 2)
```

Consequently you can declare the flex of the inputs section as:

```
.inputs-section {flex: 0 0 120px;}
```

**ie.** *make this `120px` wide, don't grow it, don't shrink it.*

and the flex of the home-team and away-team sections:

```
.home-team-section,
.away-team-section {
flex: 0 0 calc((100% - 120px) / 2);
}
```

**ie.** *make both of these **half** of the entire width of the containing `<div>` minus `120px`, don't grow them, don't shrink them.*

**Working Example:**

```css
.container {
display: flex;
}

.container div {
display: inline-block;
}

.inputs {
flex: 0 0 120px;
text-align: center;
background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.home-team,
.away-team {
flex: 0 0 calc((100% - 120px) / 2);
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
}

.away-team {
text-align: right;
}

.home-team div:nth-of-type(odd),
.away-team div:nth-of-type(even) {
width: 30%;
}

.home-team div:nth-of-type(even),
.away-team div:nth-of-type(odd) {
width: 65%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="home-team">
<div>FLAG</div>  
<div>HOME_TEAM</div>
<div>FLAG</div>  
<div>HOME_TEAM</div>
<div>FLAG</div>  
<div>HOME_TEAM</div>
<div>FLAG</div>
<div>HOME_TEAM</div>
</div>

<div class="inputs">
<div>Input1</div>  
<div>x</div>
<div>Input2</div>

<div>Input1</div>  
<div>x</div>
<div>Input2</div>

<div>Input1</div>  
<div>x</div>
<div>Input2</div>

<div>Input1</div>  
<div>x</div>
<div>Input2</div>
</div>

<div class="away-team">
<div>AWAY_TEAM</div>  
<div>FLAG</div>
<div>AWAY_TEAM</div>  
<div>FLAG</div>
<div>AWAY_TEAM</div>  
<div>FLAG</div>
<div>AWAY_TEAM</div>  
<div>FLAG</div>
</div>
</div>
```